# It seems to be clearing the last line for no reason

Tags: c

It is meant to be a terminal screensaver although it make a newline or clears the last line.
here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

int i, j, x=1, y=1, xm=1, ym=1;

int main()
{
    printf("test");
    for(;;)
    {
            struct winsize w;
            ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &w);
            for (i=0; i<w.ws_row; i++)
            {
                    for (j=0; j <w.ws_col; j++)
                    {
                            if (i == y || j == x)
                            {
                                    printf("#");
                            } else
                            {
                                    printf(" ");
                            }
                    }
                    if (i < w.ws_row-1)
                    {
                            printf("\n");
                    }
            }
            if (y >= w.ws_row-1)
            {
                    ym=-1;
            } else if (y == 0)
            {
                    ym=1;
            }
            if (x >= w.ws_col-1)
            {
                    xm=-1;
            } else if (x == 0)
            {
                    xm=1;
            }
            x=x+xm;
            y=y+ym;
            usleep(100000);
    }
    return 0;

}
```

I think it might have something to do with usleep because when I remove it there is never a blank line.

Comment: When you write something at the end of the line, the cursor goes to the next line. When this happens on the last line, the window scrolls, and this leaves a blank line.

Comment: The simplest solution is to make the inner loop go to `w.ws_col-1`.